create the location records when the Account is created and the “Number of Locations” field has some value in it
Prerequisite
Create a Custom Object and Name it Location. Relate this location object with Account using Lookup relationship.
Create a field on Account “Number of Locations” of type Number
Develop a solution that will create the location records when the Account is created and the “Number of Locations” field has some value in it. The no. of locations related to the account should be the same as the value in the “Number of Locations” field.
For Example – if the value of the “Number of Locations” field is 4 then there should be 4 location records created under that account.
accountTriggerHandler:
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert,before delete,before update,after insert) {
    
   
        if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert){
             accountTriggerHandler.createNumberOfLLocationToAccount(trigger.new);
        }
    }
    // accountclassHandler
public class accountTriggerHandler {
    public static void createNumberOfLLocationToAccount(list<account> listacc){
    List<Location__c> locationsToInsert = new List<Location__c>();

    for (Account acc : listacc) {
        // Assign numberOfLocations with a default value of 0 if Number_of_Locations__c is null
        Decimal numberOfLocations = acc.NumberofLocations__c ;

        if (numberOfLocations > 0) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfLocations; i++) {
                // Create a new Location record
                Location__c newLocation = new Location__c();

                // Set fields on the Location record based on the Account
                newLocation.Account__c = acc.Id;
                newLocation.Name = acc.Name + ' - Location ' + String.valueOf(i + 1);
                // Set other fields as needed

                locationsToInsert.add(newLocation);
            }
        }
    }

    // Insert the newly created Location records
    if (!locationsToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert locationsToInsert;
    }
}

    
    
    
    }

can someone review my code why I am not able to create associated location

DLRS or Rollup Summary Field (requires master detail rather than lookup)

You don't state what error you are seeing so we'll start by writing the triggerHandler more compactly with cleaner variable names
public static void createAccountLocations(Account[] accounts) {
  Location__c[] locations = new List<Location__c>();
  for (Account account : accounts) {
    for (Integer i = 0; i < account.Number_Of_Locations__c ?? 0 ; i++) {
       locations.add(new Location__c(
              Account__c = account.Id,
              Name = account.Name + ' - Location ' + String.valueOf(i + 1)
              ));
   }
   insert locations;
}

Notes

No need to check for empty locations collection before inserting; DML of empty lists doesn't burn Limits
Note use of ?? null coalascing operator to handle use case where Account.Number_Of_Locations__c is null - yes, you said it has default value of 0 but this future proofs your code in case that default value is reverted.
I changed your method name and variable names to be concise.
One possible issue your code (and my answer) has would be a limits exception. You can only do DML of 10,000 records in a transaction. So a batch of 200 accounts, each with 50 locations would fail as the transaction would insert 200 accounts plus 200*50 = 10,500 records.  To protect against this, you'll need to use the Limits class:


stop processing altogether if a single account has 9,999+ Locations
check the count of records against DML limits
delegate to a chained queueable the insertion the remaining accounts' locations.

For example, delegate to a chained queueable all subsequent accounts as soon as you detect that accounts.size() + locations.size() will be greater than 10,000 (DML Limits) .  I leave this as an exercise for you.
